# How to add headers in existing AWS API gateway integration request

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, aws-cloudshell

I have created a Integration Request, I am trying to add headers to that request using AWS cloudshell:

> aws apigateway update-integration --rest-api-id abcdefgh --resource-id
> abcdefghj --http-method POST --request-parameters
> {"integration.request.header.X-mobile":"context.authorizer.mobile"}

But it is not working, I have tried PUT integration as well, It was giving the below error:

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the
> PutIntegration operation: Enumeration value for HttpMethod must be
> non-empty

Answer (score 0):

Try add those command options:

- `--integration-type` eg. AWS_PROXY
- `--integration-method` eg. POST
- `--integration-uri` eg. arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LambdaForSimpleProxy.Arn}/invocations

Here you will find values exmple: [Lambda Proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html)

I had similar issue in cloudformation, when you are using integration some options are conditional [AWS::ApiGateway::Method Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html)

Unfortunately [aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigatewayv2/update-integration.html) docs doesn't mention this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding
`--integration-http-method POST`
solved it for me when doing this with AWS CLI.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html):

> For Lambda integrations, you must use the HTTP method of POST for the
> integration request, according to the specification of the Lambda
> service action for function invocations.